# Where is the jenkins profile in docker ? iIcouldn't find it (/etc/sysconfig/jenkins)

Tags: jenkins

I want to build my project by jenkins, but something was wrong. Somebody told me to update my jenkins profile `JENKINS_USER="root"`, but I couldn't find it (/etc/sysconfig/jenkins). Could someone tell me where itis?  How to resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: try creating the file if it doesnt exist

Comment: @ptierno Does creating this file when it doesn't already exist work universally across OS? For example, MacOS doesn't have a `/etc/sysconfig` directory, so it doesn't seem correct to create `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`. It also doesn't have an `/etc/default/jenkins` either, like I think I saw Redhat would. It's a shame this has to be so hard to find, when guides like this get so close but only mention `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`: http://sam.gleske.net/blog/engineering/2016/05/04/jenkins-with-ssl.html#configure-jenkins-to-use-ssl